# Recover this instance' is disabled for M4 instance type

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

In short, I'd like launch an instance **without instance store volume** using Boto. 
So far I have found this page: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-this-instance-cloudwatch-enable/

With Boto2 I do

```
    dev_sda1 = BlockDeviceType(delete_on_termination=True)
    dev_sda1.size = 150
    bdm = BlockDeviceMapping()
    bdm['/dev/sda1'] = dev_sda1
```

but it launches it with instance store volume.
The problem I have is that the recovery option is disabled for me and all I do is via Boto and Python.

Does anyone have a piece of Boto (or Boto3) code that you could share? I don't mind doing it in either of them.

**Edit 1**
Turns out that M4 is not supplied with instance store 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html

*But* why is the recovery option not enabled. it meets all criteria 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html

Comment: Why not just launch an instance type that doesn't have an instance store?  A lot of the newer, faster CPU types lack instance storage.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: it's on windows

Comment: @Vorsprung - yes but m4 works pretty well for us

Comment: @rafalf m4 instances are EBS only. They do not have an instance store. If you are launching m4 instances and you think they have an instance store then you are confused about what an instance store is.

Comment: @MarkB - you are right. why is that not enabled then. any idea?

Comment: Are you launching dedicated tenancy instances?

Comment: @MarkB - I think the problem might be that when i launched an instance it was of different type and then I changed it to m4. makes sense, does it?